# Should we allow "looking for editors" type questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Well it's more of a type of query then a question, they could also be asking for beta readers or other such things. While there is some benefit for using the site for networking, it doesn't seem to be the sort of question this site is aimed at.

I bring this up because it's a question I see come up on a lot of other writer forums I've been on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope, because, as you said, it's not really a question. It can't be answered, only responded to. This is the kind of thing that's suited for a "Looking for readers? Post here" topic on a typical forum, and Stack Exchange is not built for that at all.

Comment: Good to see there is an agreement.

Answer (score 3):

No, these would not be questions that can be answered by someone with expert knowledge of the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Not on the main site, for sure.  We could use chat for this purpose, however.